# How do i combine this keyboard switching function with login screen in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Okay, so I have a login screen function that is supposed to be intentionally bad. I found a function that switches your keyboard to alphabetical order and I have a user registration UI. how do I combine these so that when you register it flips your keyboard to alphabetical order and displays the keys while typing?

```py
from tkinter import *


def register_user():

  username_info = username.get()
  password_info = password.get()

  file=open(username_info+".txt", "w")
  file.write(username_info+"\n")
  file.write(password_info)
  file.close()

  username_entry.delete(0, END)
  password_entry.delete(0, END)

  Label(screen1, text = "Registration Sucess", fg = "green" ,font = ("calibri", 11)).pack()

def register():
  global screen1
  screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
  screen1.title("Register")
  screen1.geometry("300x250")
  
  global username
  global password
  global username_entry
  global password_entry
  username = StringVar()
  password = StringVar()

  Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below").pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "Username * ").pack()
  username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
  username_entry.pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "Password * ").pack()
  password_entry =  Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
  password_entry.pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
  Button(screen1, text = "Register", width = 10, height = 1, command = register_user).pack()

def login():
  print("Login session started")


def main_screen():
  global screen
  screen = Tk()
  screen.geometry("300x250")
  screen.title("Avan-suck")
  Label(text = "Avan-suck new inturface", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack()
  Label(text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Login", height = "2", width = "30", command = login).pack()
  Label(text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Register",height = "2", width = "30", command = register).pack()

  screen.mainloop()

main_screen()


REPLACE_DICT = {"q": "a",
                "w": "b",
                "e": "c",
                "r": "d",
                "t": "e",
                "y": "f",
                "u": "g",
                "i": "h",
                "o": "i",
                "p": "j",
                "å": "k",
                "a": "l",
                "s": "m",
                "d": "n",
                "f": "o",
                "g": "p",
                "h": "q",
                "j": "r",
                "k": "s",
                "l": "t",
                "ö": "u",
                "ä": "v",
                "z": "w",
                "x": "x",
                "c": "y",
                "v": "z",
                "b": "å",
                "n": "ä",
                "m": "ö"}
def keyboard_pressed(event):
    char_pressed = event.char
    if char_pressed.lower() in REPLACE_DICT:
        char = REPLACE_DICT[char_pressed.lower()]
        if char_pressed.upper() == char_pressed:
            # If uppercase:
            char = char.upper()
        # Insert the character
        event.widget.insert("insert", char)
        # Return "break" to stop the event
        return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: what did you try? Did you try to bind this `keyboard_pressed` to your widget? And you have to put `keyboard_pressed` before first mainloop. You need only one `mainloop` and one `Tk()`

Comment: if I put `def keyboard_pressed()` at top of code and assing `username_entry.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed)` then it works withotu any problems.

Answer (score 0):

if I put function `def keyboard_pressed(): ...` and `REPLACE_DICT` at top of code and assing

```
 username_entry.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed) 

 password_entry.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed)
```

then it works. That's all.

---

And then you can remove

```
root = tk.Tk()
text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *


REPLACE_DICT = {"q": "a",
                "w": "b",
                "e": "c",
                "r": "d",
                "t": "e",
                "y": "f",
                "u": "g",
                "i": "h",
                "o": "i",
                "p": "j",
                "å": "k",
                "a": "l",
                "s": "m",
                "d": "n",
                "f": "o",
                "g": "p",
                "h": "q",
                "j": "r",
                "k": "s",
                "l": "t",
                "ö": "u",
                "ä": "v",
                "z": "w",
                "x": "x",
                "c": "y",
                "v": "z",
                "b": "å",
                "n": "ä",
                "m": "ö"}

def keyboard_pressed(event):
    char_pressed = event.char
    if char_pressed.lower() in REPLACE_DICT:
        char = REPLACE_DICT[char_pressed.lower()]
        if char_pressed.upper() == char_pressed:
            # If uppercase:
            char = char.upper()
        # Insert the character
        event.widget.insert("insert", char)
        # Return "break" to stop the event
        return "break"


def register_user():

  username_info = username.get()
  password_info = password.get()

  file=open(username_info+".txt", "w")
  file.write(username_info+"\n")
  file.write(password_info)
  file.close()

  username_entry.delete(0, END)
  password_entry.delete(0, END)

  Label(screen1, text = "Registration Sucess", fg = "green" ,font = ("calibri", 11)).pack()

def register():
  global screen1
  screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
  screen1.title("Register")
  screen1.geometry("300x250")
  
  global username
  global password
  global username_entry
  global password_entry
  username = StringVar()
  password = StringVar()

  Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below").pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "Username * ").pack()
  username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
  username_entry.pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "Password * ").pack()
  password_entry =  Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
  password_entry.pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
  Button(screen1, text = "Register", width = 10, height = 1, command = register_user).pack()

  username_entry.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed)

  password_entry.bind("<Key>", keyboard_pressed)

def login():
  print("Login session started")


def main_screen():
  global screen
  screen = Tk()
  screen.geometry("300x250")
  screen.title("Avan-suck")
  Label(text = "Avan-suck new inturface", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack()
  Label(text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Login", height = "2", width = "30", command = login).pack()
  Label(text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Register",height = "2", width = "30", command = register).pack()

  screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```